# Magento 2 GraphQl performance

Tags: performance, graphql

I am working with magento 2 graphql.

Out of box product category GraphQl service take more the 12 sec to load fist time.

I have updated all required parameters on server but still same performance in first load.

Can anyone provide me some input which help me to increase Magento graphQl performance.

Comment: Can you provide examples on what you've done so far?

Comment: Possibly this issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/31879

Answer (score 2):

Check if Full Page Cache is enabled and try to install Varnish. Varnish is recommended for Magento 2.